# Locate and paste into ...mnt/sdcard

Tags: android, sqlite, emulation, sd-card

I am trying to paste an sqlite database containing language details for testing in an AVD emulator. The application into which it is to be tested is mysword4android-3.5.1.apk, which I have installed into the emulator, and it is running. The test database is to be placed in a file "...mnt\sdcard\mysword" - what I can't figure out and find is:

1. Where in my laptop is this "...mnt\sdcard\mysword" located - all I get are png images or xml files when I search for it on my laptop.
2. How to place this sqlite database into the location/file so that the app can access it and show it

The makers of the app have simply said to copy and paste this database into the data path where other language databases are located; and this location is "...mnt\sdcard\mysword"

P.S. I have no idea about writing program code. I am using a Windows7 laptop and the AVD emulator is running Android 4.2. If the copy-paste can work that is all I can do.

Answer (score 1):

The file is contained in an emulated SD card in the emulator and therefore not directly visible in the file system on your laptop. Use the tools provided with the Android development kit to move files between the laptop and the emulator file systems.

In particular, the `adb pull` and `adb push` commands will be helpful.